# O365\Sharepoint Site admin unable to access using Sharepoint Designer

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

If I try and access my SharePoint site using SharePoint Designer 2010 I get permission\access denied 403. I can browse to the site without any problems and modify it using the browser, any ideas whats causing the issue when using SharePoint Designer?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try below things for solving your issue:

1. Ensure the problematic site has enabled the custom script feature. You can refer to this article about “Turn scripting capabilities on or off” to check that.

https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-us/article/allow-or-prevent-custom-script-1f2c515f-5d7e-448a-9fd7-835da935584f?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

2. Refer to below article about “How to Clear Your SharePoint Designer 2010/2013 Cache”, and clear the cache of the SharePoint Designer, then compare the results.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/33469.how-to-clear-your-sharepoint-designer-20102013-cache.aspx

3. Make sure the WebClient services (Search: services.msc) is running. For the detailed information, please refer to the article:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2616712/how-to-configure-and-to-troubleshoot-mapped-network-drives-that-connec

4. Try to add your site URL to the list of trusted sites in IE settings.
5. Go to your site collection site settings > site collection administration > SharePoint Designer Settings. Make sure  you enable the SharePoint Designer.